# Re-exporting an implementation without exporting the definition

Tags: module, public, idris

Suppose I have module `M1` that defines a type in terms of another, existing type:

```
module M1 

import public Control.Monad.Identity

public export M : Type -> Type
M = Identity
```

I can of course import `M1` and use `M` anywhere expecting an `Applicative`:

```
module M2

import M1

bar : M ()
bar = pure ()
```

But what if I don't want to export `M`'s definition? In other words, I'd like to write

```
export M :: Type -> Type
M = Identity
```

so that client code can't depend on `M`'s definition, but I would still like client code to be able to access `Applicative M`.

Comment: am I right that you'll need to export the fact that `M` makes an applicative? So you'll need `Applicative` somewhere in `M`'s type signature if you're not exporting the definition? Or is it not important that `M` generates an applicative type?

Comment: @joel yeah the q is how to export `M`'s Applicative instance.